# Frequentist definition of probability and prediction?

Tags: prediction, definition, frequentist, philosophical

The [frequentist definition of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_definition_of_probability) states that:

> The probability of an event is the ratio of the number of cases favorable to it, to the number of all cases possible when nothing leads us to expect that any one of these cases should occur more than any other, which renders them, for us, equally possible.

If we want to know the probability that the price of a slice of *Pineapple Pizza* will be higher than $5 on the 1st December 2019 in a specific pizzeria in New York, then this is a unique event. It seems that it is not possible to define this probability from a frequentist perspective. Then, does this mean that we cannot define a frequentist probability for prediction? Or do we need to assume that we have the power to re-start the origin of the universe and check the value of a Hawaiian pizza slice on each repetition?

Comment: "re-start the origin of the universe" - some think our universe is not unique, there are infinite number of other universes

Comment: 1.  This is the classical definition of probability (Laplace), not the frequentist definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentist_probability .)  2. If you want to go the route indicated by your example, one could state "the entire universe is realized only once, so there are only unique events, therefore there is no probability other than subjective."  This is certainly a valid philosophical position to take, but once you have taken it, you've pretty well answered your question!

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental underlying philosophical assumption of the frequentist approach is that most events are not really unique, and certainly much less unique than what we usually tend to believe in the first place. Wearing my frequentist hat, your example

> *...price of a slice of Pineapple Pizza will be higher than $5 on the 1st December 2019 in a specific pizzeria in New York,...*

does not look like such a unique event. Just a price-setting decision for a consumer good based on past experience and demand, by a small pizza-owner that is alike thousand other that face similar economic conditions.

More formally, to say that an event is *unique*, is to say that it does *not* belong to a population, it does not share enough common characteristics with a group of other events. The moment an event is characterized as a member of a population of which we have data, we immediately know a lot about it.

Comment: But the question is about a specific pizzeria, isn't it? That is, $P($ price of a slice of Pineapple Pizza will be higher than USD 5 on the 1st December 2019 in a specific pizzeria in New York $)$.

Comment: Pineapple pizza is not specific

Comment: @Aksakal All due respect, but I think you are trying to get off on a tangent, by looking at grammar and nitpicky details, rather than the more general question: does this mean that we cannot define a frequentist probability for prediction? The example of the pizza is silly, and just a tool to discuss this general question.

Comment: @Nostradamus If this "specific" pizzeria is like hundreds of thousand of others, we can very well define what you are asking about.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos OK, so, under your definition, basically anything that is related to something else somehow can be defined as repeatable?

Comment: @Nostradamus, if you're truly speaking about an event that happens only once, then there's no point in talking about frequentist probability. What we're pointing out though, is that those events are really difficult to find

Comment: @Aksakal So, basically almost everything is repeatable so it is almost always possible to define a frequentist probability? Like, will it rain tomorrow?

Comment: @Nostradamus, I won't say *everything* but with tools such as *ergodic hypothesis*, many seemingly one off events can be seen as samples from some populations. A lot of this is indeed about wording. For instance, you could say "what is probability that I will need an unmbrella today?" which sounds quite unique, because there's only one *you* presumably. However, if you look at the weather in where you live, then suddenly it may turn out that this event can be seen as dependent on of weather pattern in the region, which can be analyzed in terms of probabilities

Comment: @Aksakal I think there is a mix up between the mathematical calculation and the interpretation/definition of the concept of probability in this reasoning. Of course, we can use measure theory and define a probability in terms of sigma algebras, but the interpretation, which is the aim of my question is a different matter, and it concerns the [philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_interpretations), rather than the mathematics, behind it.

Comment: @Nostradamus, I do not appreciate philosophy and look down on philosophers, so maybe it's best for me to abstain from this discussion. I will only hint that maybe finding a better example would keep the discussion in the lane of your preference. Pineapple pizza price is simply not a good example of a unique event.

Comment: @Aksakal Let me know if you have an example that will suit your taste and ego-biases better.